# External monitor resolutions gone after sleep

Tags: 18.04, suspend, display-resolution, xrandr, external-monitor

I have strange problem which comes when the **screens go to sleep**. I have an external monitor connected to my laptop so I have two screen.

When I connect the USB-C cable I get the resolutions 1920x1080 on both screens. This is what I want.

After the screens have gone to sleep and I wake them up, I get the resolutions 3840x2160 (native for laptop) and 1280x720 on my external monitor. The strange thing is that external monitor is missing all but three low resolutions in `xrandr`

When everythings is fine:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   3840x2160     60.00 +  59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01*   59.97    59.96    59.93  
...
DP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
...
```

after sleep the external monitor only contains the following in xrandr:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: ...
...
eDP-1-1 connected ...
...
DP-1-1 connected primary ...
1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
1024x768      70.07    60.00  
800x600       60.32    56.25
```

When I reconnect the USB-C cable everything is fine again. Does anyone have a clue on what this could come from? Could I do a workaround with some script?